# How to run multiple lines of code created by genertic programming in R?

Tags: r

I'm writing a genetic program that evolves a rule that get used in an agent model to dictate agent behaviour. The agent model is implemented as a function that accepts the rule as text, inserts it into the code, runs the agent model and returns the result which is then tested for fitness:

```
ABM <- function(evolvedRule){

#setup agents etc...

eval(parse(text = evolvedRule))

return(result)

}
```

The rule is a simple '*IF condition THEN action*' that gets assembled before the call using paste()

but I would like to include multiple ELSE IF conditions. Usually that would be done over multiple lines of code. So:

1. Will using paste() to create one really long line of R code with else ifs work?
2. How else could I create multiple lines of code and pass those to the ABM function and have them run?

Comment: The length of the string passed to `parse(text=..)` does not have a practical limit, so yes you can pass something arbitrarily long (for instance, though I don't recommend testing _this_ code, I checked with `eval(parse(text=paste0("nchar('", strrep("AAA",1e8), "')")))` and it worked and did not complain. That "expression" has 300,000,000 characters in it, likely many more than you'll contrive in your if/else/... expression.)

Comment: I see no reason why passing `"if (..) {..} else if (..) {..} else if (..) {..} else if (..) {..}"` would experience any problems. What have you actually tried?

Comment: paste with just one else but it gets confusing really fast! The main issue is probably me getting muddled in the paste command rather than R being unable to run it! Thank you for your reassurances.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused: are you passing multiple values to `evolvedRule`, meaning `length(evolvedRule)` is greater than 1? If that's the case, and you are certain that all of the expressions in it start with `if (...)`, then you can do `paste(evolvedRule, collapse=" else ")`, However, I'll caveat that with: there are dozens of ways that this can go wrong depending on how you are creating your expressions and/or evaluating them in the context of the genetic fitness-tests (or whatever).

Comment: No, you've got it exactly right. I've run a quick test and paste(), pass, and eval() will all work thanks. I don't imagine that's the way the genetic programming packages do it though. I suspect there is a much neater (and more complicated) way to do it. But this is OK.